# How to perform nested factor repeated measure MANOVA

Tags: repeated-measures, factor-analysis, manova, nested-data

I have 3 independent variables -

- Game (3 groups)
- Noise Type (2 groups - SNM (Sequential Noise Model), ZMGN(Zero Mean Gaussian Noise))
- Noise Level (5 groups - AL-AverageLow, AM-AverageMedium, N-None, L-Low, M-Medium)

Noise Type and Noise Level are nested factors such that -

- SNM - AverageLow, AverageMedium
- ZMGN - None, Low, Medium

That is:

```
                               Noise Level
                   ZGMN             |           SNM
Game      none     low     medium   |   Ave.low     Ave.Med
  ST
  TT
  Pass
```

My observations include Player Experience (PX) under different conditions. So, I'm interested to find out the interaction between the Noise Type and Game that is, Does the PX vary under different type of noise for different games.

I'm finding it hard because under Noise Type (SNM and ZMGN), I have another nested factor Noise Level. SNM has 2 Noise Levels (AverageLow, AverageMedium) and ZMGN has 3 Noise Levels (None, Low, Medium).

PX contains multiple factors - Competence, Enjoyment, Tension/Pressure, Effort. Also my comparisons are within subject means - One participant has gone through all the conditions.

Can I perform repeated measure MANOVA with nested factors?

Comment: OK, I suppose this is clear enough to be answerable now.

Comment: Are you forced to use the categorizations? In other words, it should be more informative to build models on the raw "noise levels," whatever metric they are in, than on these categories. Are you able to retrieve the original, pre-categorized metrics or values? If so, use them.

Comment: @DJohnson Yes, I kinda am forced.. cause I already have interactions analyzed for individual noise level which provided pretty good results

Comment: Ok. Why not redo the interactions on the raw or uncategorized data and see if you get *better* results?